# Why is this paragraph spamming my game output?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently, I checked my logs and looked for some evidence to punish a player on another server, and I realised that my game output is constantly flooded with this particular paragraph:

```
[22:17:17] [Client thread/FATAL]: Error executing task
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default value cannot be lower than minimum value!
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at h.a(SourceFile:61) [h.class:?]
     at avf.av(SourceFile:880) [avf.class:?]
     at avf.a(SourceFile:325) [avf.class:?]
     at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124) [Main.class:?]
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131) [launchwrapper-1.7.jar:?]
     at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27) [launchwrapper-1.7.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Default value cannot be lower than minimum value!
     at qk.<init>(SourceFile:21) ~[qk.class:?]
     at bcz.a(SourceFile:1442) ~[bcz.class:?]
     at ib.a(SourceFile:70) ~[ib.class:?]
     at ib.a(SourceFile:15) ~[ib.class:?]
     at fi$1.run(SourceFile:13) ~[fi$1.class:?]
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) ~[?:1.6.0_65]
     at h.a(SourceFile:60) ~[h.class:?]
     ... 9 more
```

This makes my output complete unreadable and prevents me from doing something I want to do.

I suspect that it is caused by the server I usually play on because this only happens when I am playing on that server.

Why is this happening? What does these lines mean? Is there any way that I can do to fix it?

Comment: What server are you playing on?  Is it modded?

Comment: It is a heavily plugged in Forge 1.7 server.

Comment: Probably the server needs to fix it. However if this writes your client, the problem is probably in some mod and not in plugins. Maybe more information can be in starting log of client. And....is it same with same modpack on Singleplayer?

Comment: I'm using the same mods (OptiFine only) for all different servers but only this server returns such a strange output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server probably has poorly coded plugin or mod that is causing an exception: when one Thread requests return values from another executing Thread the default value is lower than the minimum value of the parameter.

Unless you have full access (ability to change the plugins and such) to the server, you probably cannot stop Minecraft from printing such exception.

An easy solution to your current problem is to simply search and replace all such exceptions with nothing aka deleting it, which will make the log much more readable.

Comment: So there is no way to stop it from flooding?

Comment: Unless you create a client side mod that will override the client counsel output and filter out the exceptions